# Newly created script tag has "text/plain" type

Tags: javascript, angular

When I run my Angular web project locally (I can't share it) and I run this code in the console :

```
const tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.id = "iframe_api_script";
tag.type = "text/javascript";
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

When I display "tag" I get this :

```
<script id="iframe_api_script" type="text/plain" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

The type has become "text/plain".

Actually the type still "text/javascript" until I add the "src".

I try this on the same app on multiples browser (Chrome, Chrome incognito, Edge, Firefox) and same result. I never use Edge/Firefox so no extension on those.

But if I go to another website it's OK the type still "text/javascript".

The strangest is : If I go to my app deployed on the server (same code as locally) I got "text/javascript". If my coworkers take the same branch as me locally, they do not have the issue.

So the issue is related to my app and I realize I can't get an accurate diagnostic without showing it but do you have something in mind that could explain this behavior ?

ADDENDUM : If I change the value of "src" to something else:

- https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api234 => text/plain
- https://www.youtube.com => text/plain
- https://www.youtube2.com => text/javascript
- https://www.youtube.com/hello => text/javascript
- https://www.youtube.com/iframe => text/plain
- https://www.google.com/iframe => text/javascript

Comment: Sorry, but as you guessed, this isn't answerable without a [mcve], which includes (par of) your app.

Comment: Could be some browser extension perhaps, that tries to "block" known trackers/other unwanted scripts that way ...? Have you already tested this in a private window, with no 3rd-party extensions enabled at all?

Comment: you can simply comment the type code and by default it will take it as text/javascript

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan the type was not present and I also got the text/plain unfortunately

Comment: @CBroe I should have indicated that I never use Edge/Firefox so no extension on those :/

Comment: "If my coworkers take the same branch as me locally, they do not have the issue.  So the issue is related to my app".  If your coworkers are running the same branch and getting different behavior, that's evidence that the issue is *not* related to your app.  It's something in your local setup (a browser extension is a likely candidate).   For what it's worth running your code I see `text/javascript` for all the URLs you tried.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks for trying! I would agree with you but I had the gut feeling it was link to the app and in the end it was the case but it was kind of tricky. I'll post my findings as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue so I post it as an answer in case someone needs it one day.

Short answer : OneTrust (cookies management tool) block some scripts when cookies are rejected.

Long answer :

So the `type` switch to `text/plain` (no matter what you set before) only when you change the `src`.

You can check the `src` property with :

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(tag, "src")
```

When you do it on **non** problematic tab you get a classic :
[image]

When you do it on the problematic tab you get :
[image]

OtAutoBlock.js is a script added by our cookies management tool OneTrust.

So OneTrust overrides the `src` property of the `HtmlScriptElement` to add a custom setter. When it wants to block a script it add `text/plain` as type to prevent browser from loading it.

My coworkers accepted cookies so the script was not blocked.
I refused the cookies so the script was blocked.

In other environment (other than local) I didn't had the issue because I accepted the cookies but we just did a test and if we reject cookies the same issue appear.

You can tell OneTrust to ignore the script by adding `data-ot-ignore` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" data-ot-ignore></script>
```